# Groovy : Retrieve XML from Database

Tags: xml, oracle, grails, stored-procedures, groovy

1.I have Database columns with type in Oracle : XMLTYPE  and in MSSQL : XML

2.Have Procedure that has two IN parameters and one OUT parameter returning this XML column content.

Generally for SP(IN,IN,OUT)...call from Groovy is as following

```
sql.call '{call SP_ABC_GET_(?, ?, ?)}', [params.scode,params.version, Sql.SQLXML], { out ->
         println out

         }
```

But this doesnt seem to support the retrieving XML..(groovy call).
However , using JAVA CallableStatement Im able to .

Can anybody assist me with How can we retrieve XML data  from DB using Groovy?

Comment: Can't you just read it as Text?

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: @tim_yates: No ..i need to use this XML data for XML tree using jstree

Comment: @SérgioMichels Im looking for relevant data type for the OUT parameter something like **java.sql.Types.SQLXML**  to be used in Groovy SP Call